# symfony raw sql from table based on 2 server

Tags: php, symfony4

I have 2 database server so I defined my doctrine in following way:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                # configure these for your database server
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: 'mariadb-10.3.16'
                charset: utf8
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8
                    collate: utf8_unicode_ci

                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            customer:
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: 'mariadb-10.3.16'
                charset: utf8
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8
                    collate: utf8_unicode_ci

                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_CUSTOMER_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Now I need to make the query from table inside customer server:

```
$qb = $this->connection->createQueryBuilder()
           ->select(*)
           ->from('customer.tbl_user')
```

I am not being able to run this query. Can anybody help me how can I set up this multiple database connections?